# SQL won't let me get an average of calculated values?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, powerbi, metabase

I've attempted to utilize the SQL AVG(##) function to obtain the average of a column generated using SQL COUNT(DISTINCT(##)), or DISTINCTCOUNT(##) in PowerBI (they're both effectively the same thing). However, each attempt results in the error message 'Parameter is not the correct type.' Even when I attempt to employ separate measures in PowerBI, the operation is still restricted.

I've experimented with Google Big Query, PowerBI, and Metabase, but none of them seem to work. It appears that the issue lies in the SQL itself, or at least that's the strong indication. Is there a solution to make this work?

Comment: The best way to get help on stuff like this is to make sure your problem is entirely reproducible in the question. It will go a long way if you create some sample data, and provide the sql query against that sample data that yields your error.

Comment: `Parameter is not the correct type` means you should focus on the parameter(s), not the average function. Without knowing what that parameter is, and the query that uses it, there simply is no way to help. Please add details to you question (edit the question, don't use these comments).